# Interactive geopandas - 'positional argument : location' error

Tags: python, typeerror, geopandas

I'm not advanced in python and trying to make an interactive world map visualization using geopandas library. Whatever I try, I keep getting this ****init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'location' ** error and really frustrated about it. Obviously I'm missing something, any ideas?
I couldn't add the error image directly but i added a link.

[image: error image]

Comment: You are trying to create an instance of a class that requires a "location" argument to be passed to it, but you haven't given it that argument.

Comment: Sorry can you be more specific about that? I took the code from a tutorial, basically copy-pasted and still get the error. It looks like it working for others but not me.

Comment: Consider posting the part of your source code that is causing the error. Without knowing what class you're trying to create and seeing your working it's virtually impossible to help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) - instead, copy and paste the code and errors as [formatted code blocks](/help/formatting). When asking a question, please help us understand exactly where you're stuck with a [mre]. For more information, see the guide to [ask]. Thanks!

Comment: See https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/2187. The folium version installed on google colab is too old. You can update the version from within the notebook (see the issue linked).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me. A few select dependent packages.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| folium | 0.12.1.post1 |
| geopandas | 0.10.2 |
| mapclassify | 2.4.3 |
| pygeos | 0.12.0 |
| pyproj | 3.3.0 |

```
import geopandas as gpd
import folium
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
print(gpd.__version__, folium.__version__)
world.explore(column="pop_est", cmap="Set2")
```

Comment: I guess error was caused by google colab which uses folium's older version. I was able to run the code with Jupyter notebook. Still, thanks for your concern :)

Comment: in google Colab you can add `!pip install folium==0.12.1` (or whatever the latest version is) and then it works